# react-redux mock subscribe useStore in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, mocking

This is the element where the component logic is built, the value fragments to understand the situation

```
import { useStore } from ‘react-redux’;
const reduxStore = useStore();
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = reduxStore.subscribe(obtainDataStore);
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [obtainDataStore, reduxStore]);
```

I need to be able to generate a mock that allows me to respond to subscribers in a jest test in order to generate usability tests of my component I am doing the following

```
import useCalculatePublish from ‘./component’;
import { renderHook } from ‘@testing-library/react-hooks’;
import { useStore } from ‘react-redux’;
jest.mock(‘react-redux’);
    const store = { years: { first: ‘’, last: ‘’ }, category: ‘’, status: ‘’ };
    describe(‘’, () => {
      it(‘loaded’, async () => {
        mockUseStore(store);
        let x = await renderHook(() => useCalculatePublish(‘test’));
        console.log(x);
      });
    });
    const mockUseStore = ({ years, status, category }) => {
      useStore.mockReturnValue({
        ...mockUseStore,
        getState: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue({
          filterReducer: { years, status, category },
        }),
        subscribe: jest.fn(),
      });
    };
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this question...

Comment: I recommend that you actually don't mock your store and use your real one, like they  teach on RTL docs https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests